# Date format inconsistent cross browsers & incorrect date is saved

Tags: jhipster

I use the LocalData of Joda Date type out of the box from JHipster. The field shows in a format of mm/dd/yyyy on Google Chrome. When creating a new data, "mm/dd/yyyy" will show up in the field. On IE and Firefox, however, the data format is yyyy-mm-dd. And when creating a new data, there isn't a date format indicator in the date field.

Another problem I notice is that a date will be one day earlier after the form is submitted. For example, if I enter 1986-11-12, 1986-11-11 will be saved into a DB. That occurs on all three browsers. I assume that isn't about the front end as the other problem.

The followings is a related html code generated by JHipster without any modification:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label translate="myApp.profile.dob" for="field_dob">Dob</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob" id="field_dob"
                ng-model="profile.dob" required>

        <div ng-show="editForm.dob.$invalid">
            <p class="help-block"
                ng-show="editForm.dob.$error.required" translate="entity.validation.required">
                This field is required.
            </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

The following is a screen shot on Google Chrome:
[image: on Google Chrome with curse in the field]

And here is a screen shot on Firefox:
[image: on FireFox]

And I use the latest version of JHipster.

How to fix those problems?

BTW, I would like to use Java 8 date library instead if there isn't so much change.

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of input field do you use?

```
<input type="text" name="thedate">
```

or

```
<input type="date" name="thedate">
```

or something else?

The DB problem could be due to wrong timezones and i assume you don't only save the date, but also the time?!

When you add for example 1986-11-12, the server converts it to 1986-11-12 00:00:00. And if you use a local time (e.g. UTC+2 aka CEST - central europe summer time), your server converts it to "1986-11-11 22:00:00" which is finally saved in your database.

So, you should check, if you (partially) using datetime and not only localdate?

And for both cases I would check what's sent between the browser and the rest-endpoint, so you're able to isolate the problem to a server and/or javscript/html problem.

**Update**

The difference between chrome and IE/Firefox is due to a special handling by chrome, because it offers a built in datepicker for date-inputs. The default date format is taken from the local system setting. Look here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome

The actual format of the value (the raw-format) is always yyyy-mm-dd (according to the html rfc). This is also in chrome and only the presentation is changed by chrome. Since IE and Firefox don't offer a build-in datepicker, the raw format is used there. That's why there are different formats and why there is no datepicker in IE or Firefox.

So, you have to add a datepicker for IE/Firefox by yourself, e.g. using jquery, modernizr or an angular directive.

Comment: I add the section of HTML code in my question. The input data type is date. It was quite late last night when I noticed the date problem and hadn't look into it by debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think that a nature choice is to have datepicker from angular-bootstrap which already come with JHipster. There is quite some coding though.

Answer (score 0):

For the date format issue, I learn that [a date format filter is needed in AngularJS code](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) for a date or time field. So, it is better than the generated default AngularJS code come with a default date filter.